# Why AXIS Array Object is not mapping correctly in SOAP Client Response in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, axis, soap-client

Why Array Object is not mapping correctly in Response classes using AXIS in Java. Please find the example as below:

```
private StatementDetails[] statements;

 static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://COM...Services", "UserResponse"));

        elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("statements");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://COM...Services", "Statements"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://COM...Services", "StatementDetails"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        elemField.setItemQName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://COM...Services", "StatementDetails"));
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
    }

but the response should like as below:



<Statements>
      <StatementDetails>
       ....
      </StatementDetails>
      <StatementDetails>
       ....
      </StatementDetails>
   </Statements>
```

But it is coming as below:

```
<Statements>
       .....   // missing StatementDetails tag
   </Statements>
```

if i changed StatementDetails[] like as below

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="Statements")
   @XmlElement(name="StatementDetails")
   private List<StatementDetails> statements;
```

then getting the error shown as below:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">; nested exception is: 
    org.xml.sax.SAXException: No deserializer for {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

Can Any one help me on this.